# How to read next 10 characters after String variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, contains

I have list of text files I need to read a specific string from, which is always preceded by the string "SWEUserName=".  I have been able to print the entire line from the log, but not just the string I need.  I do want to print the line number, just not the whole line

So far this is what I've got:

```
  public static String [] openFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String searchTech = "SWEUserName=";
    int s;
    String foundTech = "";       
    File logs = new File("C:\\Users\\wfedric\\Desktop\\GD\\Java\\Learning\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\fedrictechnologies\\learning\\FSDS2.txt");
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(logs);

    int lineNumber = 1;
    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        lineNumber++;
        if(line.contains(searchTech)){
            s = 10;
            foundTech = lineNumber +" :"+ searchTech + s;
            System.out.println(foundTech);
            System.out.println(line);
        }else;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

I know I am missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure how to count the next 10 characters.  I realize at it stands in my code, I am simply printing the Line number followed by my searchTech variable, and the number 10.

I need s to hold on to the 10 characters following searchTech.  Perhaps an array is the best way?  Just not sure :(

With the above code, I have the following output, which I should expect:

```
141 :SWEUserName=10
[09/04/14 EDT:8:15:48 AM- INFO- MASC1050141409832948329] - [ HomePageURL ] - ThinClient Home Page URL - https://wls.rio.directv.com/wpservsm_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=ExecuteLogin&amp;SWENeedContext=false&amp;SWEUserName=masc105014&amp;SWEPassword=%5BNDSEnc-D%5Dji%2Fic25k%2FTB%2Fy7mqG2kcb2ndd1S3hgWC8Rfa4e1DvtwKWMGQmTzngA%3D%3D&
143 :SWEUserName=10
[09/04/14 EDT:8:15:48 AM- INFO- ] - [ webServiceRequest ] - Web service Call - RetryCounter: 0, URL: https://wls.rio.directv.com/wpservsm_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=ExecuteLogin&amp;SWENeedContext=false&amp;SWEUserName=masc105014&amp;SWEPassword=%5BNDSEnc-D%5Dji%2Fic25k%2FTB%2Fy7mqG2kcb2ndd1S3hgWC8Rfa4e1DvtwKWMGQmTzngA%3D%3D&, Type: GET
```

1st and 3rd lines are the General format I want, 2nd and 4th lines are where I get stuck returning the specific values after searchTech.

**SOLUTION** (During this process, I played with the indexOf method to include the date, and left it there)

```
public class techMatching {
static int s;
static int d;
static String sTech;
static String dTech;

public static String [] openReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String searchTech = "SWEUserName=";  
    String foundTech;
    File logs = new File("C:\\FSDS2.txt");
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(logs);

    int lineNumber = 1;
    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        lineNumber++;
        if(line.contains(searchTech)){
            s = line.indexOf(searchTech);
            sTech = line.substring(s+12,s+22);
            d = line.indexOf("[");
            dTech = line.substring(1, 22);
            foundTech = lineNumber +": "+ "(" + dTech + ")" + "|"+ sTech.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(foundTech);
            }else;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Which returned the expected output:

```
141: (09/04/14 EDT:8:15:48 )|MASC105014
143: (09/04/14 EDT:8:15:48 )|MASC105014
```

And so on.
""  ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at the methods available in the String class. Using indexOf(searchTech), you know where in the line the "SWEUserName=" is. Using substring, you can get a String consisting of part of the line.

Comment: I am giving this a try.  I keep getting an error telling me the index is out of range (-199).  The index returned in my terminal is 204, 201, 202, 205, etc...  When I state the index in a static way, it prints it out just fine.

Comment: GOT IT!  I'll update the question with my final code.  Thanks for the help! (I just had to count out the number of characters after the index I wanted :P)